# scikits.sparse installation(or build) fails on windows and anaconda (spyder)

Tags: python, windows, installation, sparse-matrix

I have been trying to install `scikits.sparse` module in python. I feel that the module I obtained needs compilation. I guessed the same as it doesn't contain `.py` files, instead there is a `cholmod.c` and a `cholmod.pyx` file in the sparse directory. I attempted to do this in 2 ways,

One from `Spyder`, by first adding the module path to `PYTHONPATH` manager and then including the following lines in the program

```
import pyximport

pyximport.install()

from scikits.sparse.cholmod import cholesky
```

This gave me the error

> ImportError: Building module scikits.sparse.cholmod failed:
>   ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files
>   (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]

Second directly in `Python 3.6`,

I installed `Microsoft Visual C++ build tools 14.0` (from Visual Studio 2015), which looked like completed installation, but the final status said, It may not have installed properly.

Then I updated `pip`,
installed `cython`, `scipy` and some other dependency of `scikits.sparse`
then on attempting installation like th following,

```
python e:\python\scikits.sparse-0.2\setup.py install
```

from command prompt returned an error,

> Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with
>   exit status 2

Is there anyway to compile and build `scikits.sparse` in windows?

Alternatively, is it possible to compile it in a `Linux` system to a `.whl` and then install it easily in windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install C++ build tool.
In my case it was the same as per yours i.e. "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
So I installed C++ build tool from the link given below.[landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools][1]

This showed me 2015 version, and that solved my issue.

Hope it's gonna work same for you too. If not, leave the comment below.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

scikits-sparse was not built for windows, only for linux